# Group Box component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a group box in Flex?

Is there any other control with same property?

I tried this [link](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=184044), but it has no answers. Also [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vertical+box+flex&oq=vertical+box+flex&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.7914j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=group+box+in+flex+developer&spell=1&sa=X&ei=7NatUcWaIsH5rAeU9ICACQ&ved=0CCgQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.bmk&fp=7e7364bc4198e8f&biw=1024&bih=636) 
did not help me in this case.

Comment: There is Group, HGroup (horizontal group) and VGroup (vertical group)

Comment: What do you expect a "GroupBox" component to do?

Comment: @Reboog711 By "GroupBox", I believe they're after the equivalent of a html fieldset - a rounded rect bevel with label that groups form elements together, like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset).

Comment: In that case; he probably wants a BorderContainer?  Or possibly a Form?

Answer (score 1):

there is a spark form element which you can use directly and you can include headings there.

As copied from the source http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e973827a8e912ac2b325a4-8000.html

```
<s:Form id="myForm" width="450" height="125">
    <s:FormHeading label="Spark Form Heading" />
    <s:FormItem label="Username:">
        <s:TextInput id="username" />
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="Enter your LDAP username" />
        </s:helpContent>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

If you just want to group elements you need to look at custom components (if they provide a source you can just modify those) like

https://www.assembla.com/code/shinylib/subversion/nodes

http://jayachandrababu.blogspot.de/2010/01/groupbox-fieldset-legend-component.html

I hope that helps

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Skinning a panel may also help. You can use panel's title as header like @Jason Sturges' provided link. Customizing panel's layout will also provide you with the group box you wanted.